Detecting rectangle surrounding object
I am using OpenCV to detect rectangle surrounding red parts of my sample image below.

My approach is to use HoughLines, then manually find 4 lines that form a rectangle. Rectangle quality is determined how many red pixels are inside and black pixels outside. This method does not work very well as can be seen here (white lines mark the "best" found rectangle).

I am not very familiar with OpenCV or object detection in general. Would it be better to use some other method for detecting the rectangle or tweak my parameters?

Hey, your question is quite broad and unclear, please read the How to Ask and adjust your question to include code as well. What language are you using anyway? Please specify in the tag

details and clarity. [mre]. all the usual things that make a question answerable.

Result of your approach will be limited by result of HoughLines. So, you should confirm HoughLines always can be provide "4 lines which consists the best rectangle".

After reading the question, my understanding is that, you need the smallest rectangle ,not polygon, that have all the red pixels inside. So assuming this is the case, I tried below approach. Thresholde image on V channel to find bright area, get contour and get minimum rectangle of largest contour.
See below code with explanation in comments. Hope this helps.
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Input image file path
filepath = "red_image.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(filepath)

#Csan
#gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#ret, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Convert to HSV and get the brighness associated channel V as the TV image is brighter than others
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = hsv_img[:, :, 0], hsv_img[:, :, 1], hsv_img[:, :, 2]

#Threshold the image to get the brightest regions
ret, thresholded_image = cv2.threshold(v, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Find the contour of bright regions
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresholded_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#Get the largest contour, i.e. one with max area
max_area=0
max_area_ctr=None
for ctr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(ctr)
    if area> max_area:
        max_area = area
        max_area_ctr = ctr

#Find the minimum rectangle that encloses the largest contour.
#This rectangle is used to draw in image.
if max_area_ctr is not None:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(max_area_ctr)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    box = np.int0(box)
    cv2.drawContours(image, [box], 0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
    cv2.imwrite("red_image_thr.jpg",image)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
else:
    print("Rectangle not found.")


Output

